# How do I disable one fan?

Tags: hardware, cooling

My MacBook Pro has two fans, however the left one is screwed up and makes a lot of noise and scrapes against the back panel (or something like that). Is it possible to disable just one fan and leave the other? I don't want to open up the computer since I want to be able to take this to the Apple store afterwards.

To get a sense for how annoying the faulty fan is, here's a [link](https://puu.sh/AUZvv/7ab726e271.m4a) to an audio file recording my laptop shutting down.

Comment: https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control ?

Comment: No. I'm looking to shut it off completely, not make it run faster.

Comment: did you actually try it?

Comment: Holy shit nevermind, make that an answer and I'll accept it. I had to manually edit the plist but you can in fact set the speed to 0. THANK YOU!

Comment: You can even overclock(? Overvolt?) the other fan slightly to make up for it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading [this fan controller program](https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) to change the fan cycles.

Comment: Note that you'll need to modify the plist using something like [Prefs Editor](http://apps.tempel.org/PrefsEditor/index.php#download) (while the app is off anyway) to set the speed outside of the range 2000-5700 (I set my left fan to 0 and the right one to 10000, although the right fan hovers at around 8000 which is fine)

Comment: @Dev Do you know if MacBook Pro fan vents are interconnected?

My 2017 MacBook Pro has a left fan that's giving problems. Until I get a replacement, turning it off won't fry a chip I hope